# Meanning of %! and %K with printf

Tags: c, format, output, printf, format-specifiers

I try to rewrite printf function and i found a strange result when use format specifier (%) with ! or K. I want to understand why i get this result.

```
    printf("%!");
    printf("%K")
```

I get output ! and K.
Thank for all response

Comment: If you want to output "%", you must put "%%" into the format string.

Comment: Neither `%!` nor `%K` mean anything.  For many `printf` implementations, the interpretation of an unrecognized `%` sequence is to just print the last character.

Comment: What did you expect to see?

Comment: for some use cas of %(charactere), i get nothing and printf return -1

Comment: when use %j i get nothing and printf return -1

Comment: When i use %K i get K and printf return 2

Comment: Why i have different result for format that mean anyting

Comment: Undefined behavior means that anything can happen. It doesn't have to be consistent.

Comment: What did you think should happen with `%K`?

Comment: `j` is a well-defined width modifier, so `%j` is a broken specifier, which explains why `printf` returns -1 for that case — it wants to see something like `%ju` or `%jx`.  Evidently this implementation of `printf` is not treating `%K` or `%!` as a serious error, it's just quietly outputting `K` or `!`, and not returning an error code.  (In other words, `%j` and `%K` are wrong for completely different reasons.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [§7.21.6.1 ¶9 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9), using an invalid conversion specification will result in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Therefore, you cannot rely on any specific behavior. Anything may happen. On different compilers, the behavior may be different. Even on the same compiler the behavior may change, if you for example update the compiler to a different version or compile with a different optimization level.

If you want the behavior to be well-defined, so that you can rely on a specific behavior, then you should only use valid conversion specifiers. You can use the `%%` conversion specification to print a literal `%`.

Comment: you said" On different compilers, the behavior may be different" But this is not entirely true.  It depends on the <c standard library> used (such as glibc) and it is not completely related to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%!"); printf("%K")` are both undefined behavior.  Any result is possible.
As part of OP's rewrite, code can do anything in these cases.